# From windows system mails is sending fine but after hosting into centos mail is sending in encrypted format

Tags: php, centos, sendmail

From windows system(locally) it is working fine but after hosting into centos mail is sending in encrypted format. Following code i'm using to send mails.

```
$boundary = md5("sanwebe");

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$from_email."" . "\r\n";



    $headers .= "CC: ".$cc."" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n"; 

    $body = "--$boundary\r\n";

    $body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

   $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
    $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message)); 




    //attachment
    if (file_exists($file_name)){

        $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=".$file_name."\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_name."\r\n";         
        $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
        $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n"; 
        $body .= $encoded_content; 

    }


$sentMail = @mail($recipient_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Ouput Mail is:

```
8de2a431c506316063ec3a4044192e46
PGh0bWw+PGJvZHk+PHN0cm9uZz5EZWFyIFNpci9NYWRhbSw8L3N0cm9uZz4gPGJyIC8+DQo8YnIg
Lz4NCgkJIEluc3RydW1lbnQgOiBHQy8wMiwgc2VyaWFsX251bWJlciA6IEMxMjA5NTMwMjQ2Nywg
bWFrZSA6U2hpbWFkenUgIG1vZGVsIDpHQyAyMDEwIFBsdXMtIEluc3RydW1lbnQgaXMgYnJlYWtk
b3duIFBsZWFzZSBhbGxvdCBzZXJ2aWNlIFBlcnNvbiA8YnIgLz4NCjxiciAvPg0KQmVzdCBSZWdh
cmRzPGJyIC8+DQpBZG1pbiw8YnIgLz4NCiAgQWRtaW4sPGJyIC8+DQpWaW10YSBMYWJzIExpbWl0
ZWQuPC9ib2R5PjwvaHRtbD4=
```

Comment: Please add the actual code of the email message you receive to the question, that probably is invalid so needs to be checked.

Comment: Above mentioned code is the actual code and getting encrypted format message to receivers side. if I add any attachment to mail that attachment is also encrypting.

Comment: That does not look like something "encrypted", more like base64 encoding. But more important: that certainly is _not_ the message code. That might be what you see in some email program, but that is something different. To understand what is wrong with your message you need to debug the code you send out, that is why I asked for it. Most email programs offer some feature like "View source code" or similar for received messages.